# Ajax control not shown when opening a url using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to click on a ajax control to upload a text file on a webpage but when i open it in selenium webdriver that ajax control is not shown. I have tried the following but it is not working.

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tabContainer_tabPanel2_btnUpload"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("element.click();");
```

Comment: Please provide the html.

Comment: How does a real user click the button?

Comment: If user cant, Selenium also cant

Comment: if i open the page normally without using selenium then that element is visible. but if i open the same webpage using selenium that element is hidden.

Comment: Then you should fix it rather than patching over the issue.

Comment: but i should get some solution for that. It is simply not shown in the newly instantiated Webdriver. I have not restricted any controls then i dont understand why am i not able to see it. Any kind of solution will work.plz help

Answer (score 2):

The code above gets an element from the tree and then tries to execute the JavaScript code `element.click()`. Those two are not related in any way. Specifically, Selenium (or rather Java) won't make any attempt to read your mind and magically connect the local variable `element` to JavaScript.

You will have to use the JavaScript DOM API to locate the element inside of `js.executeScript()`.